# Move wiki "excerpt/wiki not helpful" to top of suggested edit reject reasons list

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, rejection-reasons

Could we get these reasons moved to the top of the reject reasons list? They seem to be the most common ones I would use and they are buried and not even in the same place in the respective list.

> > [image]

Comment: i guess they are alphabetical, but that's not always helpful.